# Issue with Drools Fusion "during" temporal operator

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

I've started to work with Drools Fusion and faced strange issue with **during** temporal operator. For a reason I cannot make it too work though for example **after** operator is working fine.

Here is declaration of my event - it just contains an intervals of particular type:

```
declare WorkingDayInterval
   @role(event)
   @timestamp(event_ts_local)
   @duration(duration_in_seconds)
end
```

Here is my rule:

```
rule "Idles in Processing period"
when
 $processing : WorkingDayInterval( subcategory == "processing")
 $longIdle : WorkingDayInterval(this during $processing, subcategory == "idle",duration_in_seconds > 600)
then
    System.out.println ("Bad Idle Event:");
    System.out.println ($processing.event_ts_local);
    System.out.println ($processing.duration_in_seconds);
    System.out.println ($longIdle.event_ts_local);
    System.out.println ($longIdle.duration_in_seconds);
end
```

When I run it nothing is fired.

However when I change **during** to **after** I get following results:

```
Bad Idle Event:
Mon Feb 25 05:19:00 MSK 2013
2350
Mon Feb 25 05:20:00 MSK 2013
901
```

and looking at the values I clearly see that based on start timestamps and durations second event is inside the first event and so **duration** should have been fired.

Is it a bug in the Drools Fusion or I am doing something wrong?

BTW - I am running in a **Cloud** mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are assuming that `@duration` is measured in **seconds** when in reality Fusion expects it to be expressed in **milliseconds**. So, in your case, `$processing` event starts at `05:19:00.00` and ends at `05:19:02.35` and `$longIdle` starts at `05:20:00.00` and ends at `05:20:00.90`. As you can see, `$longIdle during $processing` is **false** but `$longIdle after $processing` is **true**.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how I missed it, just *1000 solved the problem